# markers not being displayed on the map

Tags: leaflet, markers

I have an issue. I'm trying to display some markers stored in json variable. what i'm trying to do is looping the json get x,y and then store them in markers, so that i can display the on map but this don't seem to be working for me here is the code

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([56.04351888068181, 12.695600612967427], 15);
var osmAttrib = 'Map data © <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
var osmTileLayer = new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: osmAttrib
});

map.addLayer(osmTileLayer);

var cities = {
    city: [{
            x: -7.6188009,
            y: 33.5949733,
            "osm_id": 25730724,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Casablanca",
            "alt_name": "Casablanca",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -1.9293059,
            y: 34.6778736,
            "osm_id": 26755661,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Oujda",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -5.5678716,
            y: 33.8850849,
            "osm_id": 26756035,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Meknès",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -8.49884,
            y: 33.2433309,
            "osm_id": 26756132,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "El Jadida",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -11.0986635,
            y: 28.4375526,
            "osm_id": 26756639,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Tan-Tan",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -9.5830755,
            y: 30.4211631,
            "osm_id": 27565078,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Agadir",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -9.2395332,
            y: 32.2994239,
            "osm_id": 29337459,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Safi",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -2.9281198,
            y: 35.1739922,
            "osm_id": 31380375,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Nador",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -5.531164,
            y: 31.5213295,
            "osm_id": 34992118,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Tinghir",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -6.072605,
            y: 33.8302864,
            "osm_id": 63439019,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Khémisset",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -4.0101041,
            y: 34.230155,
            "osm_id": 63443413,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Taza",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -5.2219133,
            y: 33.4361171,
            "osm_id": 206385324,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Azrou",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -9.7620903,
            y: 31.5118281,
            "osm_id": 245486763,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Essaouira",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -8.8779217,
            y: 30.4706513,
            "osm_id": 254485332,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Taroudant",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -9.7312815,
            y: 29.698624,
            "osm_id": 256948195,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Tiznit",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -6.9008369,
            y: 30.9204403,
            "osm_id": 288704798,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Ouarzazate",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -2.9407146,
            y: 35.2919028,
            "osm_id": 289031151,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Melilla",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -5.013355,
            y: 34.0341156,
            "osm_id": 289035432,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Fès",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -5.3041384,
            y: 35.8883614,
            "osm_id": 291768008,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Ceuta",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -6.8345427,
            y: 34.0224046,
            "osm_id": 299120862,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Rabat",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -8.7595462,
            y: 31.5469033,
            "osm_id": 309968105,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Chichaoua",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -15.9431274,
            y: 23.6940663,
            "osm_id": 348237703,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Dakhla",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": "Villa Cisneros"
        },
        {
            x: -10.0574351,
            y: 28.9863852,
            "osm_id": 351111110,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Guelmim",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": "Goulimine"
        },
        {
            x: -3.9301858,
            y: 35.2451143,
            "osm_id": 391512701,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Al Hoceima",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -2.3294087,
            y: 34.9266755,
            "osm_id": 391562106,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Berkane",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -1.9632308,
            y: 32.5329031,
            "osm_id": 400915111,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Bouarfa",
            "alt_name": "Būʿarfah",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -1.2303964,
            y: 32.1150479,
            "osm_id": 401232144,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Figuig",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -4.4335952,
            y: 31.9292779,
            "osm_id": 406192860,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Er Rachidia",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -6.8140167,
            y: 34.0448888,
            "osm_id": 414081770,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Salé",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -5.3742776,
            y: 35.570175,
            "osm_id": 421432226,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Tétouan",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -7.9886083,
            y: 31.6259901,
            "osm_id": 508040941,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Marrakech",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -11.6645492,
            y: 26.7435827,
            "osm_id": 569755163,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Smara",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -6.152913,
            y: 35.1952327,
            "osm_id": 583022208,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Larache",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -9.084263,
            y: 32.1082966,
            "osm_id": 1039966988,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Sebt Gzoula",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -5.7114339,
            y: 34.2264119,
            "osm_id": 1052247758,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Sidi Kacem",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -5.8987235,
            y: 34.9992176,
            "osm_id": 1052364362,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Ksar-el-Kebir",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -7.6198672,
            y: 33.0023969,
            "osm_id": 1156264376,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Settat",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -7.9581313,
            y: 32.2390335,
            "osm_id": 1210857280,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Benguerir",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -6.3533346,
            y: 32.3341927,
            "osm_id": 1274095863,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Beni Mellal",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -7.5811465,
            y: 33.2676746,
            "osm_id": 1339097697,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Berrechid",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -6.0365451,
            y: 35.4619276,
            "osm_id": 1686960487,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Assilah",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -3.3910053,
            y: 34.9769401,
            "osm_id": 1725334403,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Driouch",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -6.5701685,
            y: 34.2645699,
            "osm_id": 1863747049,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Kénitra",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": "Port-Lyautey"
        },
        {
            x: -5.8037921,
            y: 35.7771029,
            "osm_id": 1863747052,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Tanger",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -5.9272533,
            y: 34.259878,
            "osm_id": 1864970021,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Sidi Slimane",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -6.909238,
            y: 32.8855082,
            "osm_id": 1865094126,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Khouribga",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -6.5710543,
            y: 32.8625036,
            "osm_id": 1865117987,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Oued Zem",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -13.1953921,
            y: 27.154512,
            "osm_id": 1888261495,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Laâyoune",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -6.9238035,
            y: 33.9171656,
            "osm_id": 1954988722,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Témara",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        },
        {
            x: -14.4843938,
            y: 26.1272238,
            "osm_id": 2090045902,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Boujdour",
            "alt_name": "Cap Boujdour",
            "old_name": "Cabo Bojador"
        },
        {
            x: -7.3893292,
            y: 33.6958383,
            "osm_id": 2622712708,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Mohammédia",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": "Fédala"
        },
        {
            x: -2.8938247,
            y: 34.4134375,
            "osm_id": 2684455807,
            "place": "city",
            "name": "Taourirt",
            "alt_name": "",
            "old_name": ""
        }
    ]
};
var icon01 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'img/placeholder.png',

    iconSize: [25, 25], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor: [12, 12], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    popupAnchor: [2, -25] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
for (var i = 0; i < cities.city.length; i++) {

    // Create a local variable pointing to the
    // coordinate pair object at index i in the resources array of objects
    var currentCoordPair = cities.city[i];

    // Construct a 2 item array containing the x and y values of the current object
    var xyArray = [currentCoordPair.x, currentCoordPair.y];

    // Create a new marker object just like you did before
    var marker = L.marker(xyArray, {
        icon: icon01
    });


    // Add the marker to the map
    var addedMarker = marker.addTo(map);


    // Bind your popup
    addedMarker.bindPopup("Base");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check if the markers appear somewhere else on earth and not in Morocco where you probably would expect them to be?

Because Leaflet requires the coordinates to be in the order Latitude, Longitude. See also the [Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#marker) for this topic.

So changing the line

```
var xyArray = [currentCoordPair.x, currentCoordPair.y];
```

within you for loop to

```
var xyArray = [currentCoordPair.y, currentCoordPair.x];
```

solves your problem.

Comment: this was exaclty the real problem. Thanks for your answer