# Using PostGIS, GeoServer & OpenLayers for simple web mapping application?

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, openstreetmap, openlayers, google-maps

I'm very new to web-mapping and I develop a simple web mapping application for a small city called Berrechid in Morocco has a latitude 4099485 and longitude -14.2884 in Google Maps...

For that I already created 12 layers with GeoServer using the projection EPSG:26191 and it's work fine the problem is when I want to display my data on OSM map (or Google Maps... etc.) the data is to small and the zoom is focused always in center of Africa not on the my city !!!

Here is my code:

```
var extents = new OpenLayers.Bounds(293,460.544281415, 294,831.25, 299,954.8125,304,268.46875); 
   var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
controls: [
new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'div':OpenLayers.Util.getElement('dropdown-content')}),
        new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()
    ],
maxExtent: extents,
    minExtent: "auto",
    restrictedExtent: extents
},
    {projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:26191")},
    {units: 'm'},
    {allOverlays: true} 
    );

var OSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap");

 var geoportail_lyrs = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS (
        "Geoportail Lyrs",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geoportail/wms",
        {layers:"geoportail:geoportail_lyrs",transparent: true, format: "image/gif"},
        {visibility: true},
        {'displayInLayerSwitcher':true}
);

map.addLayers([OSM,geoportail_lyrs]);

map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(4099485, -14.2884),11);
```

here is the result :

[image]

I don't know why it's always focusing on Sao Tome and my data is too small.

Comment: Your latitude for Berrechid is wrong. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244843/markers-not-being-displayed-on-the-map tells me it should be 33.2676746

Comment: why this my data from google map !!!

Comment: Google Maps  tells me latitude is 33.2602523, longitude is  -7.5984837 and altitude is 14 ~ https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Berrechid,+Morocco/@33.2602523,-7.5984837,14z

Comment: Coordinates in other projections are: EPSG:3857 ~ http://epsg.io/map#srs=3857&x=-843929.365633&y=3930887.531344&z=15 and EPSG:26191 ~ http://epsg.io/map#srs=26191&x=296723.739708&y=298829.356967&z=15&layer=osm

Comment: thanks man for your answer but can your tell me how to transform my bounds from EPSG:26191 to EPSG:3857 ?

Comment: GeoServer will reproject for you, you just have to request the data in the projection you want

Comment: thanks man i found the solution ans it is the projection 900913 ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of issues with your code:

1. Your bounding box coordinates are badly formatted - `var extents = new OpenLayers.Bounds(293,460.544281415, 294,831.25, 299,954.8125,304,268.46875);` should not have commas in the numbers it will confuse OpenLayers.
2. Your map projection will be changed to EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) when you add the OpenStreetMap layer. So you will need to reproject your bounds and centre point from 26191 to 3857.
3. `map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(4099485, -14.2884),11);` is mixing metres and degrees in one point and neither of them will be right as I said in point 2.

Comment: great answer thanks man it's working fine by projection 900913 ;)